# How to start functions in parallel, check if they are done, and start a new function in python?

Tags: python, parallel-processing

I want to write a python code that does the following:

- At first, it starts, say, 3 processes (or threads, or whatever) in parallel.
- Then in a loop, python waits until any of the processes have finished (and returned some value)
- Then, the python code starts a new function

In the end, I want 3 processes always running in parallel, until all functions I need to run are run. Here is some pseudocode:

```
import time
import random
from multiprocessing import Process

# some random function which can have different execution time
def foo():
    time.sleep(random.randint(10) + 2)
    return 42

# Start 3 functions
p = []
p.append(Process(target=foo))
p.append(Process(target=foo))
p.append(Process(target=foo))

while(True):
    
    # wait until one of the processes has finished
    ???

    # then add a new process so that always 3 are running in parallel
    p.append(Process(target=foo))
```

I am pretty sure it is not clear what I want. Please ask.

Comment: Multiprocessing is somewhat more complex than multithreading in Python, my advice is to use `threading` if you can. The `is_alive` method can then be used to know whether a thread is finished or not, alternatively, if you have to wait for the threads to terminate, you can use their `join` method.

Comment: @SergeBallesta Could you provide an example?

Comment: Alternatively, you could find an example in the standard library at `multiprocessing.Pool`. To use threads, you could just use `multiprocessing.dummy.Pool` which has the same interface but internally uses threads.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you really want is to start three processes and feed a queue with jobs that you want executed. Then there will only ever be three processes and when one is finished, it reads the next item from the queue and executes that:

```py
import time
import random
from multiprocessing import Process, Queue

# some random function which can have different execution time
def foo(a):
    print('foo', a)
    time.sleep(random.randint(1, 10) + 2)
    print(a)
    return 42

def readQueue(q):
    while True:
        item = q.get()
        if item:
            f,*args = item
            f(*args)
        else:
            return
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    q = Queue()
    for a in range(4):  # create 4 jobs
        q.put((foo, a))
    for _ in range(3):  # sentinel for 3 processes
        q.put(None)

    # Start 3 processes
    p = []
    p.append(Process(target=readQueue, args=(q,)))
    p.append(Process(target=readQueue, args=(q,)))
    p.append(Process(target=readQueue, args=(q,)))

    for j in p:
        j.start()
    #time.sleep(10)
    for j in p:
        j.join()
```

Comment: With that code I get an error `AssertionError: can only join a started process`

Comment: I forgot to start the processes. And you left me with an error calling `randint`.

Comment: Now I get `TypeError: foo() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given`

Comment: Sorry, edits incomming.... I added a param to `foo()` to show when each has finished...

Comment: Code seems to work, and it seems to do what I want! Thanks a lot! 
I need to understand the code a bit more, but so far it looks great!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229209/discussion-between-alex-and-quamrana).

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `Pool` of the multiprocessing module.

```
my_foos = [foo, foo, foo, foo]

def do_something(method):
     method()


from multiprocessing import Pool
with Pool(3) as p:
    p.map(do_something, my_foos)
```

The number 3 states the number of parallel jobs.
`map` takes the inputs as arguments to the function `do_something`
In your case `do_something` can be a function which calls the functions you want to be processed, which are passed as a list to inputs.

Comment: This is absolutely the correct answer, I just wanted to add that the `concurrent.futures` module is also an option (especially if it turns out the workload is suitable for multithreading despite the GIL)

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I am not sure where my 'foo' comes into play here, and how I start a new function when one of the 3 functions have completed

Comment: @Alex you do not start the functions by your own. The Pool takes it.

Comment: I get a Runtime Error

Comment: ```An attempt has been made to start a new process before the
        current process has finished its bootstrapping phase.

        This probably means that you are not using fork to start your
        child processes and you have forgotten to use the proper idiom
        in the main module:

            if __name__ == '__main__':
                freeze_support()
                ...

        The "freeze_support()" line can be omitted if the program
        is not going to be frozen to produce an executable.
```