# How to send data from a child in mutiprocessing in python?

Tags: python, multiprocessing

In the following I have a working code that runs three functions at the same time. If one function finishes, the next function from the queue is used. It works all fine, except I am unable to store the outputs from the funcions.

The variable `all_times` at the end is empty. I expected it to have 10 integer values.

What am I missing? See further below for a non-successful try to fix this problem with `Pipes`.

```
import time
import random
from multiprocessing import Process, Queue

# Some random function which can have different execution time
def foo(a):
    t = random.randint(1, 10) + 2
    print(f"Starting foo {a} with time {t}")
    time.sleep(t)
    print(f"Ending foo {a} with time {t}")
    return t

all_times = []

def readQueue(q):
    while True:
        # item is a list of (function, *args)
        item = q.get()
        if item:
            f,*args = item
            t = f(*args)
            # Store the output from the function call
            all_times.append(t)
            print(f"Job finished with time {t}")
            print(all_times)
        else:
            return
    
if __name__ == '__main__':

    # Create the queue of all jobs
    q = Queue()
    for a in range(5):  # create 4 jobs
        q.put((foo, a))
    for _ in range(3):  # sentinel for 3 processes
        q.put(None)

    # Start 3 processes
    p = []
    p.append(Process(target=readQueue, args=(q,)))
    p.append(Process(target=readQueue, args=(q,)))
    p.append(Process(target=readQueue, args=(q,)))

    for j in p:
        j.start()
    for j in p:
        j.join()

    # Print the list of all outputs 
    print(all_times)
```

Here is what I have tried to 'fix' this problem using pipes:

```
import time
import random
from multiprocessing import Process, Queue, Pipe

# Some random function which can have different execution time
def foo(child, a):
    t = random.randint(1, 10) + 2
    print(f"Starting foo {a} with time {t}")
    time.sleep(t)
    print(f"Ending foo {a} with time {t}")
    child.send([t])
    child.close()
    return t

all_times = []

def readQueue(q):
    while True:
        # item is a list of (function, *args)
        item = q.get()
        if item:
            f,*args = item
            t = f(*args)
            # Store the output from the function call
            all_times.append(t)
            print(f"Job finished with time {t}")
            print(all_times)
        else:
            return
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    parent, child = Pipe()


    # Create the queue of all jobs
    q = Queue()
    for a in range(5):  # create 4 jobs
        q.put((foo, child, a))
    for _ in range(3):  # sentinel for 3 processes
        q.put(None)

    # Start 3 processes
    p = []
    p.append(Process(target=readQueue, args=(q,)))
    p.append(Process(target=readQueue, args=(q,)))
    p.append(Process(target=readQueue, args=(q,)))

    for j in p:
        j.start()
    for j in p:
        j.join()

    # Print the list of all outputs 
    print(all_times)
```

When running this code I get an error:

```
ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 61] Connection refused
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Global variables aren't shared, but you can use the same queue to return the results:

```py
import time
import random
from multiprocessing import Process, Queue

# Some random function which can have different execution time
def foo(a):
    t = random.randint(1, 10) + 2
    print(f"Starting foo {a} with time {t}")
    time.sleep(t)
    print(f"Ending foo {a} with time {t}")
    return t

def readQueue(q):
    while True:
        # item is a list of (function, *args)
        item = q.get()
        if item:
            f,*args = item
            t = f(*args)
            # Store the output from the function call
            q.put(t)
            print(f"Job finished with time {t}")
        else:
            return
    
if __name__ == '__main__':

    # Create the queue of all jobs
    q = Queue()
    for a in range(5):  # create 4 jobs
        q.put((foo, a))
    for _ in range(3):  # sentinel for 3 processes
        q.put(None)

    # Start 3 processes
    p = []
    p.append(Process(target=readQueue, args=(q,)))
    p.append(Process(target=readQueue, args=(q,)))
    p.append(Process(target=readQueue, args=(q,)))

    for j in p:
        j.start()
    for j in p:
        j.join()

    # Print the list of all outputs 
    all_items = []
    while not q.empty():
        all_items.append(q.get())
    print(all_items)
```

Output:

```
Starting foo 0 with time 4
Starting foo 1 with time 6
Starting foo 2 with time 6
Ending foo 0 with time 4
Job finished with time 4
Starting foo 3 with time 3
Ending foo 1 with time 6
Job finished with time 6
Ending foo 2 with time 6
Starting foo 4 with time 8
Job finished with time 6
Ending foo 3 with time 3
Job finished with time 3
Ending foo 4 with time 8
Job finished with time 8
[4, 6, 6, 3, 8]
```

This particular implementation could benefit from `multiprocessing.Pool`:

```py
import time
import random
import multiprocessing as mp

def foo(a):
    t = random.randint(1, 10) + 2
    print(f"Starting foo {a} with time {t}")
    time.sleep(t)
    print(f"Ending foo {a} with time {t}")
    return t

if __name__ == '__main__':
    with mp.Pool(3) as p:
        result = p.map(foo,range(5))
    print(result)
```

```
Starting foo 0 with time 9
Starting foo 1 with time 11
Starting foo 2 with time 5
Ending foo 2 with time 5
Starting foo 3 with time 3
Ending foo 3 with time 3
Starting foo 4 with time 7
Ending foo 0 with time 9
Ending foo 1 with time 11
Ending foo 4 with time 7
[9, 11, 5, 3, 7]
```

Answer (score 0):

Your all_time is not shared between your processes. Every subprocess gets a local copy and updates only that.

If you want to share an array between processes, you can do that using `multiprocessing.Manager()`.  See https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#managers for documentation.

Your code might start working if you just replaced your all_times initialisation with

```
all_times = multiprocessing.Manager().Array()
```

but I cannot test or verify that.  Managers propagate to all of your processes, global variables do not. Your all_times must of course be initialised before you launch your subprocesses, otherwise they do not inherit it, but I assume this is not a problem if you can reference the global variable now.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but this line yields an `EOFError`.

Comment: Let me try to test it and see what is wrong with it. Managers are the prescribed solution to this, just needs some fine tuning.

Answer (score 0):

You should really have given me attribution for my [code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66370661/4834).

Another way of getting data back is a return `Queue()`:

```py
import time
import random
from multiprocessing import Process, Queue


# some random function which can have different execution time
def foo(a):
    t = random.randint(1, 10) + 2
    print(f"Starting foo {a} with time {t}")
    time.sleep(t)
    print(f"Ending foo {a} with time {t}")
    return t

def readQueue(q,r):
    while True:
        item = q.get()
        if item:
            f, *args = item
            t = f(*args)
            r.put(t)
        else:
            return


if __name__ == '__main__':
    q = Queue()
    r = Queue()
    for a in range(4):  # create 4 jobs
        q.put((foo, a))
    for _ in range(3):  # sentinel for 3 processes
        q.put(None)

    # Start 3 processes
    p = [Process(target=readQueue, args=(q,r)) for _ in range(3)]

    for j in p:
        j.start()

    for j in p:
        j.join()

    r.put(None)
    all_times=[]
    while True:
        item = r.get()
        if item:
            all_times.append(item)
        else:
            break
    print(all_times)
```